# Upload Image from iOS to WCF, error 415(unsupported media)

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, wcf, http

I'm trying to upload a photo taken by the iphone to the **WCF RESTful server**, i've looked all over the web for examples and other answers around the issue, but i can't give with the solution.

The app is written in **iOS6**, and i'm using **AFNetworking 2.0** to upload the image. As in the simulator the camera doesn't work, i've been trying with a library photo. I think the problem is in format differences, **WCF is requesting for a Stream parameter**, and i don't know how AFNetworking is sending the info...

Here is the **WCF code:**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FileUpload")]
        public void FileUpload(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\sample.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                f.Close();
                stream.Close();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Recieved the image on server");
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR:  " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**iOS code:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Users/juan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0001.JPG"];
    [manager POST:@"http://192.168.2.3:8732/wave/FileUpload" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Testing the web service in **fiddler**, it throws the same error by sending an image, **415 unsupported media**.

I let the **app.config** of the server:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
    executionTimeout="14400"   />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.waveWS">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/wave"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"
              contract="WcfJsonRestService.IWaveWS"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize ="50000000" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" >

          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="50000000" />

          <security mode="None" />

        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
```

Any idea or suggestion how to solve this?
Every idea is welcome

**EDIT:**
Finally i solved myself, the problem was in the app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebConfiguration"
                 maxBufferSize="65536"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"
                 transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfJsonRestService.waveWS">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.waveWS">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/wave"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
        bindingConfiguration="WebConfiguration"
              contract="WcfJsonRestService.IWaveWS"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Comment: How much is the size, in byte of the image you are trying to send? With your code you will receive max 10000 bytes

Comment: In fiddler i used an 97,6 KB image for testing, in iOS simulator i saved an image from google images...

Comment: with this line: `stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);` you can read maxmium 10000 bytes, your image is larger than the buffer, so this is the 1 problem

Comment: With WCF you can directy handle the Stream

Comment: good point, but when debugging the server, it never reach the FileUpload(Stream stream) method...

Comment: You can try to take a look here, i don't now if it will help:
[RestFul Service step by step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide)